# File command not accepting wild card characters

Tags: linux

On my Linux machine, I can use the file command to list the contents of a directory by using it this way:

```
file /home/user/*
```

It prints the file type for each file in the /home/user/ directory. This way, I can get to know the list of all the files in that directory.

However, on a remote Linux machine, I am not able to use the wild card character with file command.

```
file /home/user/*
/home/user/*: cannot open `/home/user/*' (No such file or directory)
```

Does file command not support wild card characters on certain versions of Linux? Or is this is a restriction?

Thanks.

Comment: What shell are you using on the remote? Run `echo $0`

Comment: Note that `ls /home/user/` will show the files in a directory without using a wildcard. You can add `-l` for more information, though not of course what `file` shows.

Comment: It is running bash shell.

Comment: Yes, I can use the ls command as well. However, in this specific case I need to use file command.

Comment: @NeonFlash was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for explaining me the details :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `file` utility doesn't handle wildcards, the shell does...

The shell is likely `bash` or `dash` or `sh`, or something similar - you can run `echo $0` at a prompt to see what's running.

---

As mentioned above, the wildcards are handled by the shell (not the application), and the expansion's default behaviour might be a little unexpected. Bash, for example, will use the following behaviour:

- If `/home/user` either doesn't exist, or has nothing in it, then `/home/user/*` will not expand, but will remain as-is (i.e: `/home/user/*`).
- If `/home/user` is a directory with two files `a` and `b` in it, then `/home/user/*` will expand to `/home/user/a /home/user/b`.

With bash, you can:

- Disable "[*globbing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))" entirely by running `set -f`, or
- Expand a "*glob*" to nothing if it doesn't match anything by running `shopt -s nullglob`.

---

This means that either:

- The remote shell doesn't support globbing at all
- The remote shell has globbing disabled by default (try running `set +f` to enable it)

---

If your end goal really is to "*run `find` on all entities in `/home/user/`*", then you could try the following:

```
find /home/user/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 \
    | xargs -0 file
```

- `-maxdepth 1` prevents recursion
- `-type f` shows only files (not directories, symlinks, etc...)
- `find`'s `-print0` and `xargs`' `-0` arguments are used together to use a NUL character (`\0`) to separate entries, as special characters line newline (`\n`) are valid in filenames.
- `xargs` will use records provided via `stdin`, and use them as additional parameters to the specified command (`file` in this case)

---

#### Default (`set +f` / `shopt -u nullglob`)

```
$ tree
.
└── x

1 directory, 0 files
$ echo glob x/*
glob x/*
```

```
$ touch x/a x/b
$ tree
.
└── x
    ├── a
    └── b
$ echo glob x/*
glob x/a x/b
```

#### No Globbing (`set -f` / `shopt -u nullglob`)

```
$ tree
.
└── x

1 directory, 0 files
$ echo glob x/*
glob x/*
```

```
$ touch x/a x/b
$ tree
.
└── x
    ├── a
    └── b
$ echo glob x/*
glob x/*
```

#### Null Glob Expansion (`set +f` / `shopt -s nullglob`)

```
$ tree
.
└── x

1 directory, 0 files
$ echo glob x/*
glob
```

```
$ touch x/a x/b
$ tree
.
└── x
    ├── a
    └── b
$ echo glob x/*
glob x/a x/b
```